# JS Dynamic Link to point to root / in CI

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have setup my CI in a sub directory under my apache /localhost/ci_app/

Now I have some JS file under /localhost/ci_app/assets/js/code.js

Inside code.js I load a script dynamically

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "/assets/js/another_script.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'my_other_script'));
```

In CI config I have `$config['base_url'] = '/ci_app/';` but everytime I load the page I get the script calling `http://localhost/assets/js/another_script.js`.

I need the script to be pointing to `http://localhost/ci_app/assets/js/another_script.js`

Comment: Try to leave base_url empty in config, CI is pretty god in guessing it. Then, try to call your script like this:  js.src = "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/another_script.js"; It should work...

Comment: this won't work. doesn't execute inside .js

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it carefully, thought this is inside your view...

Comment: you could see my answer it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it in two ways,

your js script could call this function and it will give you the base url you want

```
(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = getBaseUrl() + "/assets/js/another_script.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'my_other_script'));

function getBaseUrl() {
    var l = window.location;
    var base_url = l.protocol + "//" + l.host + "/" + l.pathname.split('/')[1];
    return base_url;
}
```

and you could change your base_url in config like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_app/';
```

and it could work.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">` inside the `<head>` of your page. This resolves all relative paths to your `$config['base_url']` setting.